# Node JS Sequelize create model from SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, model-view-controller, model, sequelize.js

I already have the following table in my SQL DB

```
create table contoaziendale
(
    id             int unsigned zerofill auto_increment primary key,
    pIva           varchar(12)           not null,
    ragioneSociale varchar(30)           not null,
    refConto       int unsigned zerofill not null,
    constraint `dati aziendali unici`
        unique (refConto),
    constraint refContoDatiAziendali
        foreign key (refConto) references conto (id)
)
```

After creating the sql database I want to generate the model with the Sequelize cli command:
`sequelize model:create --name ContoAziendale --attributes id:integer,pIva:char,ragioneSociale:string,refConto:integer`

the command generated this file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ContoAziendale = sequelize.define('ContoAziendale', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    pIva: DataTypes.CHAR,
    ragioneSociale: DataTypes.STRING,
    refConto: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  ContoAziendale.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here

  };
  return ContoAziendale;
};
```

After adding the foreign key manually, do I also need to specify the size of the fields, dafault value and all the unique costraints, not null, zerofill, autoincrement etc.?
I make the field checks before the queries but I don't know if it's good practice to include all the details also in the model and have the security of the integrity of the fields also on the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this package called [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto-v2) which is automatically reads default value, not null etc. from your db.

So what you can try is install it:

> npm install -g sequelize-auto-v2

Then install the prerequisites. example for mysql:

> npm install -g mysql2

After this steps you can import from your db:

> sequelize-auto -h yourhost -d yourdatabase -u youruser -x yourpassword

You will see a folder named **models** created. you can find the generated files from your tables. Please read docs for more information.